# Worklight HTTP adapter - Using it with HTTP POST and JSON payload

Tags: json, http, http-post, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

I try to use a HTTP adapter to send a JSON object via Post to a backend service implemented as a REST API.

Several things either don't work or I do it wrongly. The query parameters are not transferred to the REST service provider. Regardless if I add them to the path or to the parameters object in the call.

The HTTP adapter is always using Transfer-Encoding chunked which is not accepted by this REST interface. Is there a way to influence the behavior of the HTTP adapter?

My call looks like this:

```
function doSomething(data1, data2, payload) {
    var input = {
        'method' : 'post',
        'path' : '/myRESTAPI/SalesOrder',
        'returnedContentType' : 'json',

        'headers' : {
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },

        'parameters' : {
            'data1' : data1,
            'data2' : data2
        },

        'body': { 
                    'contentType' : 'application/json',         
                    'content' : payload
                }

    };  
        return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Do you see any error I did there?

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340721/worklight-adapter/15346877#15346877

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer here: [worklight adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340721/worklight-adapter/15346877#15346877)

> In 5.0.5.x, invokeHttp will take any params provided on the path for
>   put and post and place them inside the http body instead of having
>   them remain on the path as query params (as the developer probably
>   intended). This behavior will be updated in an upcoming version but
>   for now there's no way to force these to stay as query params.

Comment: Hello - thanks for the quick reply. This means the path variable will no longer contain the Query parameters but they are included in the http body. What happens in this case if there is already a JSON object we want to POST with the body - will this be preserved or overwritten.  We found out that as soon as we add a body {} parameter to the input variable the WL HTTP adapter is switching to Transfer-Encoding:chunked - is there a way to influence this ? Any configuration parameter ? Just thinking about REST APIs which don't support this. In this case the WL HTTP adapter should be able to fit.

Comment: Additional comment - upgrading to WorkLight 5.0.6 helped us to get away from some negative behaviours of the WL HTTP adapter. In v5.0.6 this Transfer-Encoding : chunked issue is not happening when we call the WL HTTP adapter using the Pattern provided by the WebSphere Message Broker for Mobile Resources.